# Using react Hook, shows missing dependency in case of useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback

I am learning the hooks in ReactJs and stuck to some kind of warnings like dependencies.
Here in [src/pages/home](https://github.com/sharmarajat01/useCallback/blob/master/src/pages/home.js), I am using useCallback in it. And One more question, Could you please give me real life condition where I need to use useCallback and useMemo, in my project in future. Means, When I should go for useMemo and when to go for useCallback.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a dependency array as second parameter. Please refer to the [official React docs for hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

As a code example

```js
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```

please note the second parameter of useCallback, the dependency array.

In general `useMemo` is used for memoized values and by convention `useCallback` is used for memoized functions. They are very similar.

Comment: Hey @Julian thanks for the answer, i already got that dependency array's solution but the main concern is, when i will need to memoized any value or function? Any condition can you elaborate?

Comment: Basically the condition is if it is a function or a value. It is still a bit opinionated.

Comment: If I would like to replace the useCallback with useMemo in [this](https://github.com/sharmarajat01/useCallback/blob/master/src/pages/demo.js) , like replace this -  `const increment = useCallback(() => setC(c => c + delta),[delta])` with `const increment = useMemo(() => setC(c => c + delta),[delta])` then it is not working as expected. And in the dependency array, i wrote `delta` which is a value not a function.

Comment: Are you there @Julian

Comment: I think you want to add a function. Try `const increment = useCallback(() => () => setC(c => c + delta),[delta])`